# fireEvent.scroll from React Testing Library is not updating classList on second call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a class component in my React project that represents my navigation bar. I am using `window.scrollY` to update a boolean state `scrolled`.

When the user scrolls, the class `nav-shadow` should be added to the navbar div's `className` property.

The code runs perfectly but one of my tests are failing when I run them all together.

Here is my code:

**AppNav.tsx**

```
class AppNav extends Component<any, {scrolled: boolean}> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scrolled: false
        };
        this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
    }

    onScroll() {
        const scrollY = window.scrollY;
        this.setState({
            scrolled: scrollY >= 75
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div aria-label="navigation" className={`${this.state.scrolled ? "nav-shadow" : ""}`}>
                <p>Navbar Code...</p>
            </div>
        );

    }

}

export default AppNav;
```

**AppNav.test.tsx**

```
describe("AppNav", () => {
    const { getByLabelText } = renderWithRouter(<AppNav/>);

    const appNav = getByLabelText(/navigation/i);

    // PASS
    it("should be in the document", () => {
        expect(appNav).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    // PASS
    it("should not have nav-shadow as class if window scroll is less than 75", () => {
        Array.from(Array(74).keys()).forEach(scrollY => {
            fireEvent.scroll(window, {
                target: {
                    scrollY
                }
            });
            expect(appNav.classList.contains("nav-shadow")).toBe(false);
        });
    });

    // FAIL
    // But PASS if ran individually
    it("should have nav-shadow as class if window scroll is more than or equal to 75", () => {
        Array.from(Array(100).keys()).map(i => i + 75).forEach(scrollY => {
            fireEvent.scroll(window, {
                target: {
                    scrollY
                }
            });
            expect(appNav.classList.contains("nav-shadow")).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

**Passing Tests**

App Nav

- should be in the document
- should not have nav-shadow as class if window scroll is less than 75

**Failed Tests**

- should have nav-shadow as class if window scroll is more than or equal to 75

Debugging the code, I found that the `nav-shadow` class was not being added when I run the whole test suite. However, the call is being added when the individual test is ran individually.

I am using the react testing library and jest's jsdom.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you say your tests run fine individually then it may be best to sandbox and call `renderWithRouter(<AppNav/>)` and `getByLabelText(/navigation/i);` for each test, rather than once, so you're resetting the js-dom instance each time.

Comment: @ourmaninamsterdam I will definitely try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say your tests run fine individually, then it may be best to sandbox and call `renderWithRouter(<AppNav/>)` and `getByLabelText(/navigation/i)` for *every* test, rather than once at the top of all of your tests. This will ensure you're resetting the js-dom instance for each test.

See this sandbox with passing tests: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mclean-n0gfs?file=/src/App.test.js (this uses `render` rather than `renderWithRouter` but the result should be the same)